# how to solve modulus question for $x^5 + 4x$

Tags: number-theory

I was wondering that when finding all solutions is it sufficient enough to say that $x^5 + 4x$ congruent to $0$ mod $5$ has solutions when $x=0,1,2,3,4$

Also when checking for congruence say mod $5$ are we only allowed $x$ values less than $5$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only values less than $5$ which makes it pretty easy to brute force. However, also note that Fermat's little theorem says
$$x^5\equiv x\mod 5$$
so that $x^5+4x=5x=0$ modulo $5$ for any $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\,0,1,2,3,4\,$ is a complete system of representatives of residues modulo $5$, you are done. But you can save some work by noting that $\rm\:f(x) = x^5 + 4x\:$ is odd, i.e. $\rm\:f(-x) = -f(x).\:$ Therefore $\rm\:f(n)\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:f(-n) = -f(n) \equiv 0.\:$ Hence since $1,2$ are roots so too are $\rm\, -1\equiv 4,\,$ and $\rm\,-2\equiv 3.$

Similarly this optimization works for *even* functions: $\rm\:f(-x) = f(x).\:$ We can often halve our work by working with the balanced residue system $\rm\, 0,\pm1, \pm2,\ldots$ vs. the unbalanced system $\rm\,0,1,2,\ldots$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally, by Fermat's little Theorem, $\rm\:x^5 \equiv x,\:$ so $\rm\:x^5 + 4x\equiv 5x\equiv 0.$